# Apache runs php scripts as user nobody, cron runs php scripts as user

Tags: php, permissions, cron, cpanel

My default cpanel set up runs apache as user "nobody". So when I run a php script via a browser that outputs a file, that file has ownership nobody:nobody. When I run the script from a cron job logged in as user "fred", the output files are owned by fred:fred
I need both browser and cron to overwrite the same file. The issue I have is that if one "user" creates the file, the other one can't overwrite it.
Please can you let me know where the fundamental problem is and a possible solution. Permissions on the files are 0775.

- Do I need to set up groups - adding the user to the same group as nobody? If so how?
- How do I get the cron job to run as user nobody?

Many thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user

Answer (score 0):

Try you code after changing **permission** of the file as **0777**.
But that creates a security issue as anyone can edit your file then.

I have a logic you need to implement to:

1. Create a shell script that copy the contents of **temp** file to your **actual file**.
2. From PHP you need to update only **temp** file and Shell can read it as temp file will have read permission for everyone.
3. Use **ssh2_exec** command to execute the shell script with your Linux UserName and Password.

For **ssh2_exec** manual follow this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Hope This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that create a security issue since I would be creating a file with write permission for everyone?

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I don't think I want to put the root password for my server in a shell script - that's not good for me. I'm still looking for an answer - is there a way to run the cron job as "nobody"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my solution to this was to create a crontab for user "nobody".
I've got a standard cpanel installation and so went to /var/spool/cron created an entry for nobody. Ran crontab -e to edit it and install.
Now the php runs as nobody in the cron job exactly the same as if through a browser. All files written belong to nobody with only rw permissions for nobody.